# Unable to resize image before uploading to Google Storage

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I have the following code with reference to https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/661, but it doesnt work, the default unsized image is being stored.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='productimages')
    price=models.FloatField()

    def generate_thumbnail(self,src):
        image = Image.open(src)  # in memory
        image.thumbnail((400,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        buffer = BytesIO()
        image.save(buffer, 'JPEG')
        file_name = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name)
        temp_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(buffer, None, file_name, 'image/jpeg', len(buffer.getbuffer()), None)
        return temp_file
        

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image=self.generate_thumbnail(self.image)
        print(self.image.width) #prints the original size
        print(self.image.height)
        super(Product,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you have your App in any GCP product? App Engine, Cloud Functions, VM in GCE?

Answer (score 1):

if the `PIL` library is not working then you might use `OpenCV` as a workaround

```py
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(<your Image name>)
cv2.resize(image, size=(600, 600))
cv2.imshow(image)
cv2.imwrite(filename='resized image.png/.jpg', image)
```